Need assistance generating clip path for the attached image
I would like to know how I can generate the required mask for the attached image. I have tried various methods but I am unable to get the rounded corners with the mask per the given image.
Is there an alternative method to create the mask or using clip-path?


check this simplest example and recreate your version-
https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_mask-image6

Please note that primarily asking for a generator is asking for an external resource and that would be off-topic. I removed that sentence so that your question remains on-topic. Please ad more details what you exactly you tried and how it was not working providing the code of your attempt as a [repro].

@SahilDhir this is not a helpful link. it is something the OP already stated to have tried but will not allow him to have rounded corners. Besides that, it is just a code editor that you have on SO itself.

This question is similar to: How to make 3-corner-rounded triangle in CSS. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Yes, this is somewhat simillar to the rounded corner example, however I was unable to use the same method provided in that question/answer to achieve the required outcome and why I was seeking for further advise. Appreciate the comments and sorry for requesting tool/software recommendation. Shall keep this in mind :)

You already have the image so use it as a mask:


img {
  mask: url(https://i.sstatic.net/cWfRcqyg.png) center/contain no-repeat;
}

body {
  background: pink;
}
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/114/300/300">



I would edit the image to make it fully black but it doesn't really matter as long as you have the transparent/non-transparent parts.

Thank you for the answer. This actually did resolve the problem and I was unaware of using an existing image as a mask. Saved alot of time trying to generate a clip path :)
